# disaster in tables

Tags: tables, dcolumn

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r|d{2}|d{1}|d{0}|d{-2}|}
aaaaaaa     & bbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccc        & ddddddd & eeeeee & ffffff & gg \\
    abcdefg      & abcdefg        & abcde         &  123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\
    abcdef       & abcdef         & abcd          &  123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4 \\
    abcde         & abcde          & abcde         &  23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45 \\
    abcd      & abcd           & abcd          &  3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45 \\
    abc            & abc            & abc           &  23.4   & 123.45 & 23.45  & 123.4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{l|c|r|d{2}|d{1}|d{0}|d{-2}|}
aaaaaaa     & bbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccc        & ddddddd & eeeeee & ffffff & gg \\

abcdefg     &
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}{r} zzzzz\\ zzzz\\ zzz\\ zz\\ z\\ \end{tabular}}
                             & abcde         &  123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\

abcdef  &    & abcd          &  123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4 \\
    abcde     &    & abcde         &  23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45 \\
    abcd  &    & abcd          &  3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45 \\
    abc        &    & abc           &  23.4   & 123.45 & 23.45  & 123.4 \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Questions

- what is the difference between `{2}, d{1}, d{0}, d{-2}`? According to manual it number of decimal places, but this option does not cut the numbers, doesn't change 23.45 into 23.4 (for `d{1}`), what for is this option?
- in manual is `\newcolumntype{,}{D{.}{.}{2}}` but doesn't work (Error:  Illegal pream-token (d): `c' used.) why and what's the difference?
- look at second table, second col, how to do it without nesting tables? how to align column to right and later place in the center?

Comment: What is bad with nested tabulars?

Comment: The `dcolumn` package only typesets the numbers it doesn’t evaluate and rounds them. It is better to give them in the form of `<digits before the sep>.<digits after the sep>`, say `D{.}{.}{3.2}`. Why don’t you use `siunitx` package? This allows for rounding (and much more). Take a look at the examples at [tag:siunitx].

Comment: For your second question the error means that you defined a column type `,` but used an undefined column type `d`.  The other questions seem to have been answered already in the answers.

Answer (score 7):

With `siunitx` you have a very powerful interface for this kind of tables. I also prefer `booktabs` commands and to avoid vertical rules. Since the first attempt caused an overfull by 15pt, I used a local modification to `\tabcolsep` to reduce a bit the intercolumn space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1.1pt}
\begin{tabular}{
 l
 c
 r
 S[table-format=3.2]
 S[table-format=3.2]
 S[table-format=3.2]
 S[table-format=3.2]
}
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccc & {ddddddd} & {eeeeee} & {ffffff} & {gg} \\
\midrule
abcdefg & abcdefg        & abcde  &  123.45   & 123.45   & 123.45   & 123.45 \\
abcdef  & abcdef         & abcd   &  123.4    & 123.4    & 123.4    & 123.4 \\
abcde   & abcde          & abcde  &  23.45    & 23.45    & 23.45    & 23.45 \\
abcd    & abcd           & abcd   &  3.45     & 3.45     & 3.45     & 3.45 \\
abc     & abc            & abc    &  23.4     & 123.45   & 23.45    & 123.4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{A good table}
\end{table}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `dcolumn` package's `D` column type lets you specify how much space (in digits) LaTeX should set aside for the decimal part of the number; optionally, one can specify the number of digits for the body of the number (before the decimal point) as well. This matters for *where* the numbers will be typeset, but not for how many digits will actually be printed. Setting the third argument of `D` to `-1` is a shortcut for the package to say, "let LaTeX autoformat the numeric columns as best it can." More-negative numbers are counterproductive, as your example code shows. (Aside: If you want LaTeX to cut off and/or round digits automatically, you should use the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package, which is of a far more recent vintage than `dcolumn` is.)

What really gets the numeric columns into trouble, formatting-wise, is that you have fairly long headers that are not typeset without any kind of "protection". All material in a column of type `D` is, by default, assumed to be numeric and typeset in math mode. Since LaTeX can't find a decimal point in "dddddd", "eeeee", "ffffffff", and "gg", it just lines the up strings so that the last character occupies the ones-column, i.e. is placed immediately to the *left* of the (imaginary) decimal point.

The remedy requires two steps: First, encase the non-numeric headers in something like `multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` to inform LaTeX that they aren't numeric. You probably don't want those headers to be typeset in math mode anyway, do you? Second, use a column specification such as `D{.}{.}{2}` or, better yet, `D{.}{.}{3.2}` to get well-centered numerical data in the columns of type `D`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{g}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}

width of textblock:

\hrule

\bigskip

before:

\begin{tabular}{l|c|r|d{2}|d{1}|d{0}|d{-2}|}
aaaaaaa     & bbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccc        & ddddddd & eeeeee & ffffff & gg \\
abcdefg     & abcdefg        & abcde         &  123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\
abcdef      & abcdef         & abcd          &  123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4 \\
abcde       & abcde          & abcde         &  23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45 \\
abcd        & abcd           & abcd          &  3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45 \\
abc         & abc            & abc           &  23.4   & 123.45 & 23.45  & 123.4 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

after:

\begin{tabular}{l|c|r|g|g|g|g|}
aaaaaaa     & bbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccc        
& \mc{ddddddd} & \mc{eeeeee} & \mc{ffffff} & \mc{gg} \\
abcdefg     & abcdefg        & abcde         &  123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\
abcdef      & abcdef         & abcd          &  123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4 \\
abcde       & abcde          & abcde         &  23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45 \\
abcd        & abcd           & abcd          &  3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45 \\
abc         & abc            & abc           &  23.4   & 123.45 & 23.45  & 123.4 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a table heading, insert `\multicolumn{1}{c}{heading}` to override the D column type. Here I demonstrate the idea using the first table, leaving the second table unchanged for comparison.

1. The alignment {c} can be of your choice: {l} {r}
2. `d{2}` means 2 decimal digits. If this is negative, any number of decimal places can be used in the column, and all entries will be centred on the separator.
3. `\newcolumntype{,}{D{.}{.}{2}}`: the comm`,` means the separator in the .tex ﬁle. Thus it will usually be ‘.’ or ‘,’. In your case you used a period `.`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r|d{2}|d{2}|d{2}|d{2}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{aaaaaaa}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{bbbbbbbbbbbbbb} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ccc}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{eeeeee} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ffffff} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{gg} \\
abcdefg     & abcdefg        & abcde         &  123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\
abcdef      & abcdef         & abcd          &  123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4 \\
abcde       & abcde          & abcde         &  23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45 \\
abcd        & abcd           & abcd          &  3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45 \\
abc         & abc            & abc           &  23.4   & 123.45 & 23.45  & 123.4 \\
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r|d{2}|d{1}|d{0}|d{-2}|}
aaaaaaa     & bbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccc        & ddddddd & eeeeee & ffffff & gg \\
abcdefg     &
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}{r} zzzzz\\ zzzz\\ zzz\\ zz\\ z\\ \end{tabular}}
                             & abcde         &  123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 & 123.45 \\
abcdef  &    & abcd          &  123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4  & 123.4 \\
abcde   &    & abcde         &  23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45  & 23.45 \\
abcd    &    & abcd          &  3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45   & 3.45 \\
abc     &    & abc           &  23.4   & 123.45 & 23.45  & 123.4 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You specify maximum number of digits after period (or the other separator). Numbers are adjusted to the right side and for shorter numbers some place is reserved to make all periods one under another.